# How to properly space and position navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

How do I move by Brand slightly to right and  move About Portfolio and Contact on right side with some space left to their right without using margin and padding? Something like done here http://qlip.in/

```
<div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li id="brand"><a href="#">Brand</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li id="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>



*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navbar{  
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background-color:rgb(114, 40, 114);
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color:rgb(114, 40, 114);
  height:80px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

ul #brand{  
  text-align:center;


}

ul #about{

}
ul #portfolio{

}

ul #contact{

}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a:focus{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `width: calc(100% - 50px);margin: 0 auto;`

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navbar{  
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background-color:rgb(114, 40, 114);
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color:rgb(114, 40, 114);
  height:80px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);             /*  added property  */
  margin: 0 auto;                       /*  added property  */
}

ul #brand{  
  text-align:center;
}

ul #about{

}
ul #portfolio{

}
ul #contact{

}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a:focus{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li id="brand"><a href="#">Brand</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li id="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```